# HyperLedger Fabric - configtx.yaml policies - joining channel receives access denied

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am working through the [HyperLedger Fabric CA Operations Guide [Create and Join Channel]](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operations_guide.html#create-and-join-channel).

After remoting into the `cli-org1` with `docker exec -it cli-org1 sh` I can create the channel with:

```
peer channel create -c mychannel -f /tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer1/assets/channel.tx -o orderer1-org0:7050 --outputBlock /tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer1/assets/mychannel.block --tls --cafile /tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer1/tls-msp/tlscacerts/tls-0-0-0-0-7052.pem
```

But when I join the channel with:

```
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1-org1:7051
peer channel join -b /tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer1/assets/mychannel.block
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: proposal failed (err: bad proposal response 500: access denied for [JoinChain][mychannel]: [Failed verifying that proposal's creator satisfies local MSP principal during channelless check policy with policy [Admins]: [This identity is not an admin]])
```

I think this is because of the permissions/policies in the `configtx.yaml` but I'm not sure. The section [Create Genesis Block and Channel Transaction](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operations_guide.html#create-genesis-block-and-channel-transaction)
 provides an incomplete or outdated [configtx.yaml](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configtx.html) so I had to improvise my own, here:

```
---
################################################################################
#
#   Section: Organizations
#
#   - This section defines the different organizational identities which will
#   be referenced later in the configuration.
#
################################################################################
Organizations:

  - &org0

    Name: org0

    # ID to load the MSP definition as
    ID: org0MSP

    # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
    MSPDir: /Users/me/projects/fabric-xx/org0/msp

    Policies:
      Readers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Readers"
      Writers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Writers"
      Admins:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

  - &org1

    Name: org1

    # ID to load the MSP definition as
    ID: org1MSP

    # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
    MSPDir: /Users/me/projects/fabric-xx/org1/msp

    AnchorPeers:
      # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
      # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
      # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
      - Host: peer1-org1
        Port: 7051


    Policies:
      Readers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Readers"
      Writers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Writers"
      Admins:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

  - &org2

    Name: org2

    # ID to load the MSP definition as
    ID: org2MSP

    # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
    MSPDir: /Users/me/projects/fabric-xx/org2/msp

    AnchorPeers:
        # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
        # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
        # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
      - Host: peer1-org2
        Port: 7051
    
    Policies:
      Readers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Readers"
      Writers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Writers"
      Admins:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Capabilities
#
#   - This section defines the capabilities of fabric network. This is a new
#   concept as of v1.1.0 and should not be utilized in mixed networks with
#   v1.0.x peers and orderers.  Capabilities define features which must be
#   present in a fabric binary for that binary to safely participate in the
#   fabric network.  For instance, if a new MSP type is added, newer binaries
#   might recognize and validate the signatures from this type, while older
#   binaries without this support would be unable to validate those
#   transactions.  This could lead to different versions of the fabric binaries
#   having different world states.  Instead, defining a capability for a channel
#   informs those binaries without this capability that they must cease
#   processing transactions until they have been upgraded.  For v1.0.x if any
#   capabilities are defined (including a map with all capabilities turned off)
#   then the v1.0.x peer will deliberately crash.
#
################################################################################
Capabilities:
    # Channel capabilities apply to both the orderers and the peers and must be
    # supported by both.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        # V1.3 for Channel is a catchall flag for behavior which has been
        # determined to be desired for all orderers and peers running at the v1.3.x
        # level, but which would be incompatible with orderers and peers from
        # prior releases.
        # Prior to enabling V1.3 channel capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers and peers on a channel are at v1.3.0 or later.
        V1_3: true

    # Orderer capabilities apply only to the orderers, and may be safely
    # used with prior release peers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        # V1.1 for Orderer is a catchall flag for behavior which has been
        # determined to be desired for all orderers running at the v1.1.x
        # level, but which would be incompatible with orderers from prior releases.
        # Prior to enabling V1.1 orderer capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers on a channel are at v1.1.0 or later.
        V1_1: true

    # Application capabilities apply only to the peer network, and may be safely
    # used with prior release orderers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        # V1.3 for Application enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.3.
        V1_3: true
        # V1.2 for Application enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.2 (note, this need not be set if
        # later version capabilities are set)
        V1_2: false
        # V1.1 for Application enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.1 (note, this need not be set if
        # later version capabilities are set).
        V1_1: false

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Application
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for application related parameters
#
################################################################################
Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the application side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Application policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Application/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Orderer
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for orderer related parameters
#
################################################################################
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
    # Available types are "solo" and "kafka"
    OrdererType: solo

    Addresses:
        - orderer1-org0:7050

    # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
    BatchTimeout: 2s

    # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
    BatchSize:

        # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
        MaxMessageCount: 10

        # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch.
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB

        # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
        # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the orderer side of the network
    Organizations:
      - *org0

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Orderer policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Orderer/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        # BlockValidation specifies what signatures must be included in the block
        # from the orderer for the peer to validate it.
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

################################################################################
#
#   CHANNEL
#
#   This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for channel related parameters.
#
################################################################################
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Channel policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        # Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        # By default, who may modify elements at this config level
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    # Capabilities describes the channel level capabilities, see the
    # dedicated Capabilities section elsewhere in this file for a full
    # description
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

################################################################################
#
#   Profile
#
#   - Different configuration profiles may be encoded here to be specified
#   as parameters to the configtxgen tool
#
################################################################################
Profiles:

  OrgsChannel:
    Consortium: SampleConsortium
    <<: *ChannelDefaults

    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
        - *org1
        - *org2

  OrgsOrdererGenesis:
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Capabilities:
      <<: *ChannelCapabilities
    Orderer:
      <<: *OrdererDefaults
      OrdererType: solo    
      Addresses:
        - orderer1-org0:7050


      Organizations:
      - *org0
      Capabilities:
        <<: *OrdererCapabilities

    Consortiums:
        SampleConsortium:
          Organizations:
            - *org1
            - *org2
```

Is it the permissions in this `configtx.yaml` that are preventing the  peer from joining?

Also, in my `configtx.yaml`, I have the `MSPDir` set to the MSP directory on the host filesystem. Should this be set to the directory that the MSP will be in the container? e.g.

```
MSPDir: /tmp/hyperledger/org1/msp
```

Answer (score 0):

The same issue happened to me a week ago, Yes, that configtx.yaml is outdated, make sure you have copied admins certs correctly to the peers.
If you are douting on the policies then change **Majority** to **ANY**.

That MSPDir is only required for the generation of genesis.block
If your building a fabric 2.x network then this [configtx.yaml](https://github.com/cmjagtap/BasicNetwork-2.0/blob/master/artifacts/channel/configtx.yaml) is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The authority related to peer join in configtx is the `Channel - Polices - Admins`

```
Channel:
    Polices:
        Admins:
```

However, Look at your command, I can see that `peer channel create` worked normally.
This already executed the command with admin permission, and the verification was valid.

In other words, it seems that permissions are not the problem.
One suspicious situation is that `CORE_PEER_ADDRESS` is set to `org1`.

If you were executing the command with an organization other than `org1` in the `peer channel create` step, there is a problem with your command.

---

Check the `CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID` and `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH` environment variables at the `peer channel join step`.

```
echo $CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID
echo $CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH
```

If it is not set, it may be set to the `core.yaml` setting value in `FABRIC_CFG_PATH` or the peer's dafault value, and the MSP may not match.

Set this to org1's and try again. like this

```
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1-org1:7051
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=org1MSP
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer1/<your_admin_msp_path>
peer channel join -b /tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer1/assets/mychannel.block
```

---

[P.S] This is a suggestion by suspicion that the organization's administrator permission when `peer channel create` is different from `peer channel join`. so.. it may not be the correct answer for you.